# What is different about "normal", "weird", and "strange"

Tags: adjectives

One can say "It is normal to feel weird" and "It is weird to feel normal". The same pairing works for "It is normal to feel strange" ("It is strange to feel normal") and "It is normal to feel useful ("It is useful to feel normal.") Any two of these adjectives can be paired in this way ("It is strange to feel useful.") But it seems that most adjectives that describe how one feels will not work: "It is normal to feel happy", but not "It is happy to feel normal".  Other adjectives that don't work at all or well: I feel-- angry, elated, sad, afraid, joyous, frustrated, down, rotten, fat, etc.

What properties of an adjective permit its use in the paired construction I've specified?

Comment: You can say that it is X to feel Y where X is a meaningful adjective, and Y is an adjective of feeling. 'Normal' can be both.

Comment: One is reminded that 'awful pretty' and 'pretty awful' both 'work' (in the register of Popeye, at least).

Comment: I would think this is merely evolutionary and ever-changing in our English tongue. In context to our modern understanding of language the first phrases you noted are so widely accepted, that one understands it, even though it is a peculiar anthesis certainly. My simple response: Time decides all.

Comment: Bear in mind that "normal", in most of the above examples, is being used in a somewhat tongue-in-cheek fashion.

Comment: It's not tongue-in-cheek. Let's say you are taking LSD and your friend says to you "Don't worry. It's normal to feel weird".

Comment: Don't do drugs, kids